# How do I target directory in mod_rewrite htaccess with multiple variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use a single `.htaccess` file for both root directory and admin directories.

In trying to have clean URLs I want to use the `admin/index.php` file when admin is in the URI. Otherwise use the root dir `index.php`.

This is what I have, which works perfect for the first variable (eg. localhost/admin/users), however results in a 404 if I put the second variable (eg. localhost/admin/users/add_user).

Please help or simplify, I'm pulling my hair out...

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove trailing '/'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^admin/?$ /admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?controller=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?controller=$1&method=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?controller=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&id=$3 [QSA]
```

Comment: Code looks fine. Have you tried inverting the order of the admin rules, for example? Longest top, shortest bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `localhost/admin/users/add_user` doesn't work is because you're regex for capturing the **add_user** grouping is `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)`. Note, that amongst the matching set of characters, `_` isn't one of them. That's why the rule isn't applied because the regex doesn't match. You can try making it much more general:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ /admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?controller=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?controller=$1&method=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?controller=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&id=$3 [QSA]
```

Essentially, replacing all of the `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` with `([^/]+)`.

Comment: Thanks @Jon really appreciate it! You've pointed out that I was missing the `_` character in the regex. I've instead added an `_` to the list of inclusions - this has fixed it. Eg. `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)`